# Checking for missing items in a ragged panel stored in a data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I have a large data set

```
 dim(dt)
 [1] 422096    162
```

where `dt` is a data.table with a key of `tic`. I am trying to make a measure for each group of how many missing entries I have. The groups are time series, and dt contains a `date` column, which is an R date, and a `book_lev` column, my variable of interest.

This is my code so far:

```
dt <- dt[sumdt]
sumdt <- dt[ ,list(min.date=min(date), max.date=max(date)), by="tic"]

sublengths <- dt[,list(tslen=length(date)),by=tic, mult="last"]
bt2 <- dt[sublengths, mult="first"]
bt2[, max.year:=extractyear(max.date)]
bt2[, min.year:=extractyear(min.date)]
bt2[, data.fullness:=tslen/(max.year - min.year + 1)]

dt <- dt[bt2]
```

My idea was that I create this data.fullness value which should equal 1 if there are no holes in the time series. I realize that I may have some NA's in my `book_lev` column, so I would like to further restrict. Also, in general I am new to data.tables and I would like to see if there are better ways to write what I have just written.

A small sample of the data, which you can load using R's `load` command, is available here: http://econsteve.com/r/dt_sample.Robj

Comment: Could you post a subset of your data (e.g. containing a half a dozen rows from a couple of years, and maybe 4 or 5 columns)? You'll get a better answer that way, and save us some mental energy. Also, I don't see the `bl2` column referenced in your code. Should it be?

Comment: @Josh A subset of the data is in the following R object. http://econsteve.com/r/dt_sample.Robj

Comment: @JoshO'Brien I did not reference the bl2 column. It should actually be book_lev. I am making the edit in the original post. Thanks so much for the help.

Comment: Only time for a quick hint ... create your time series vector from first to last date, say daily, called `ts` then something like `dt[CJ(unique(tic),ts), sum(is.na(book_lev)), by=tic]`. See `?CJ`. Then maybe add `roll=TRUE` to join to the prevailing observation.

Comment: @stevejb -- First, thanks for adding a link to the data.  If you change its suffix from `.Robj` to `.Rdata`, most GUI-using folks will be able to open it by simply double-clicking on the downloaded object. Second, do let me know if I'm missing some impt. piece of your question in my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(First, a caveat.  I'm not sure I correctly understood what you want your `data.fullness` variable to summarize.  Based on the dataset you've linked to, I'm taking it to be the proportion of years with some data, in the interval from the first measured year to the last measured year.)

Here is the approach I'd take to the problem as I **do** understand it:

```
## FIRST, DEFINE A COUPLE OF FUNCTIONS

extractYear <- function(X) {
    as.numeric(format(as.Date(X, format="%m/%d/%Y"), "%Y"))
}

calcFullness <- function(YRS) {
    length(unique(YRS))/(diff(range(YRS))+1)
}

## THEN SET TO WORK ON YOUR DATA.TABLE

key(dt) <- "tic"
dt[, year:=extractYear(datadate)]

# Extract summaries for each level of tic
ticSumm <- 
    dt[, list(min.year = min(year),
              max.year = max(year),
              data.fullness = calcFullness(year)), by=tic]
ticSumm
#       tic min.year max.year data.fullness
# [1,] AMZN     1995     2010             1
# [2,]   GM     1950     2010             1
# [3,]  XOM     1950     2010             1


# Merge summary back into dt
dt <- dt[ticSumm]
```

Comment: thank you for the answer. I am trying this now. I think you got it. Thanks so much for answering the question. If it works I'll accept and you get the points bounty.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a rectangular data frame and would like to restrict to complete observations, you can create a vector of booleans indicating fully observed rows of data with the `complete.cases` function. This is assuming you have cleaned data and consistent formatting of missing values using R's `NA`.

This boolean vector can be used to subset the value directly, or using the `subset` function.

It's not clear to me from your problem description or sample code how the dt object is formatted, but you may need to use some combination of loops to successfully get 2 dimensional slices of your data where `complete.cases` can be applied.

Comment: I think that very few of my observations are truly "complete". I would like to select the ones that are a given percentage complete. Thanks anyway.